# opts_current: how does it work in knitr?

Tags: r, knitr

I am trying to set up different figure size in different chunks. I first define a global settings using:

```
opts_chunk$set(fig.width=7, fig.height=7)
```

Then, for the specific chunks, I use:

```
opts_current$set(fig.width=7, fig.height=14)
```

But the later is always neglected. So, how does opts_current really work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For specific code chunks, put the chunk options in the chunk header, e.g.

````
```{r fig.width=7, fig.height=14}
````

These are called local chunk options, which will override global chunk options (temporarily for this specific chunk).

Comment: Thank you, yihui. This works! So in which case is opts_current$set() useful then?

Comment: If you use some chunk options frequently in most code chunks, you set them in global options instead of typing local chunk options over and over again.