# knitr::opts_current: When is it safe to use?

Tags: r, knitr

This is practically a duplicate of [opts_current: how does it work in knitr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25776547/opts-current-how-does-it-work-in-knitr), but I am looking for a broader answer.

I like to use the general knitr recipe of

````
```{r fig-this-one, fig.scap=current_scaption, fig.cap=current_caption, eval.after=c("fig.scap", "fig.cap")}
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point()
current_scaption <- "My short caption"
current_caption <- "My long caption"
```
````

The `opts_current$set()` documentation has me sufficiently worried about accidentally messing with it, but I'm curious.  Is there any difference between using `eval.after` and `opts_current$set()`?  Based on https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1656, it appears to be OK.

Comment: As warned on the help page `?knitr::opts_current`, you'd better not call its `$set()` method. I'd say that it won't work in the way you'd expect in most cases. In this specific case, you should definitely use `eval.after`.

Comment: @YihuiXie, thanks for the quick reply.  I've been playing around with how to more efficiently generate captions for figures, and I'd like to try to find a way that works better in my workflows.  I was hoping `knitr::opts_current` was that way, but I appreciate that it is not.  What I'd really like to be able to do is add attributes to figures themselves and have those be automatically extracted during generation of the LaTeX.  Is there a simpler way to do that?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. Please feel free to ask it in a separate post.